# NSObject not retaining

Tags: objective-c, function, class, nsobject, retain

Process -

NSObject Class used to generate a card with certain properties. This is added to a MutableArray and used accordingly. However, after the function to determine the hand outcome in another class, the MutableArray loses all it's values.

Now I know a MutableArray simply points to the objects as opposed to holding them, so for it to lose all it's values I'm assuming the objects are being swept up by ARC.

```
-(void)rankHand {
    NSString *echo = [Hand returnHandRank:_hand withString:false]; // 7 values in _hand
    // 0 values in _hand.
    NSLog(@"%@", echo);

}
```

After breakpointing to see the issue, the issue arises after `returnHandRank: withString:`

```
@interface Cards : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *face;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *symbol;
@property (nonatomic) int prime;
@property (nonatomic) int rankByInt;

+(NSMutableArray*)createDeck:(id)sender {
    [sender removeAllObjects];
    NSArray *faces = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K", nil];
    NSArray *suits = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"h",@"d",@"c",@"s", nil];
    NSArray *primes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:41],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:13],[NSNumber numberWithInt:17],[NSNumber numberWithInt:19],[NSNumber numberWithInt:23],[NSNumber numberWithInt:29],[NSNumber numberWithInt:31],[NSNumber numberWithInt:37], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        Cards *card = [[Cards alloc]init];
        card.face = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", faces[i % 13]];
        card.suit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", suits[i / 13]];
        card.rankByInt = i % 13;
        card.symbol = [Cards symbolForSuit:card.suit];
        card.prime = [[primes objectAtIndex:(i % 13)] intValue];

        [sender addObject:card];
    }
    [sender shuffle];

    return sender;
}
```

Creates the `_deck` then `_hand` is filled by

```
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:0]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:1]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:3]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:4]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:5]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:7]];
[_hand addObject:[_deck objectAtIndex:9]];
```

`returnHandRank: withString:` is a very long function in the `Hand` class. So that is why I'm assuming they're not being retained.

Can anyone elaborate? I see it pointless to add the cards again from the `_deck`, it will it be the best solution?

EDIT: Added `returnHandRank: withString:`

```
+(NSString *)returnHandRank:(id)cards withString:(BOOL)returnString {
    NSArray *combinations = [self returnCombinations];

    cards = [self organizeCardsRankOrder:cards];

    __block int maxRank = 0;
    __block int maxValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [combinations count]; i++) {
        NSArray *splitString = [combinations[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; // splits the combination string.

        NSArray *pointerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[splitString[0] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[splitString[1] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[splitString[2] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[splitString[3] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[splitString[4] intValue]],
                                 nil]; // turns the combinations into int values in an array.

        NSMutableArray *fiveCardHand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [cards objectAtIndex:[[pointerArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]],
                                 [cards objectAtIndex:[[pointerArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue]],
                                 [cards objectAtIndex:[[pointerArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]],
                                 [cards objectAtIndex:[[pointerArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue]],
                                 [cards objectAtIndex:[[pointerArray objectAtIndex:4] intValue]],
                                 nil]; // Create the 5 card hand for the combination loop we are in, we'll now check this to see what rank it returns.


        //Check for hand rank.

        fiveCardHand = [self organizeCardsRankOrder:fiveCardHand];

        NSArray *fiveCardHandOrganized = fiveCardHand;

        int strength = [self handRankWithFiveCards:fiveCardHandOrganized];

        if (strength > maxRank) {
            maxRank = strength;
            maxValue = 0;
        }

        int value = [self associateStrengthToHand:fiveCardHandOrganized andHand:strength];

        if (value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }

    if (returnString) {
        return [self handForStrengthWithStrength:maxRank];
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", maxValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: "so for it to lose all it's values I'm assuming the objects are being swept up by ARC" Well, you're wrong about that. It would make no sense if that could happen. Obviously if an object has been added to an array, the array retains the object. — It sounds like your `returnHandRank:withString` may not do what you think it does. But you have elected, for some reason, not to show it, even though you yourself say it is the heart of the matter. That makes it difficult to help.

Comment: @matt Well, I was under the impression it was reference semantics. However, if you say I'm wrong I guess I am. I've added the function to the above question.

Comment: Where is the `_hand` instance variable declared and where is it assigned to? It may be being overwritten somewhere by an empty array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There have been a few recent question involving combinations, so unless you are creating accounts we suspect there is homework afoot... No problem, let's see if we can point you in the right direction. However we cannot answer the question, not because it might be homework but because there is not sufficient information to do so.*

> Now I know a MutableArray simply points to the objects as opposed to holding them,

Correct so far...

> so for it to lose all it's values I'm assuming the objects are being swept up by ARC.

but now completely wrong :-( You are misunderstanding how automatic memory management in Objective-C works. First forget "retain", modern ARC-based management is about *ownership* - whether a *variable* storing a reference asserts ownership over the object the reference references. When it does assert ownership the *variable* has the attribute *strong*, when it stores a reference but does not assert ownership then it has the attribute *weak* (there are some other ownership attributes you will come across later, they can be ignored for the moment). Object reference variables by default have the attribute *strong*.

Let's try an analogy:

- Consider a balloon ("object"), it will float away unless it is held down; and a hand ("variable"), which holds things.
- Many different hands can hold strings (references) attached to the same balloon.
- If the hand holds a string tightly (strong) the ballon cannot float away.
- If the string is just laying on the palm of the hand (weak) the ballon will float away unless at least one other hand is holding another string attached to the ballon tightly.
- A balloon will not float away as long as at least one hand is holding a string tightly.
- ARC is the breeze, it blows away balloons not held tightly.

An unannotated variable defaults to *strong*, so when a reference is stored in it the variable asserts ownership of the referenced object and it will not be cleared away by ARC. An instance variable of a class, or a standard (strong) property, all assert ownership. All the standard collections (arrays, dictionaries, sets) assert ownership over the objects referenced by the references stored in the collection.

Therefore, if you store a reference in an `NSMutableArray` the referenced object will not be cleared away by ARC as long as the reference remains in the array. If you mutate the array and remove a reference then the object referenced by it will be recycled (returned to the available memory pool) by ARC **if and only if** there are no other references to it stored in strong variables.

The array itself will stay around as long as a reference to it is stored in a strong variable. When there is no strong reference remaining to the array the array itself will be recycled by ARC, in the process all references stored in the array will be removed and if those references are the last strong ones to the referenced objects they too will be recycled.

Hope that helps and understanding how this works will help you find out where you are either emptying your array, or losing all strong references to the array itself; e.g. by assigning a new reference (or `nil`) to the variable(s) referencing the array.

Now let's look at some of your code:

```
NSArray *suits = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"h",@"d",@"c",@"s", nil];
```

This is old style syntax, you can more easily create an `NSArray` using an *array literal*, `@[ ... ]`:

```
NSArray *suits = @[@"h", @"d", @"c", @"s"];
```

There are no `NSMutableArray` literals so you use an `NSArray` one an make a mutable copy: `[@[ ... ] mutableCopy]` or the shorter `@[ ... ].mutableCopy` (opinions differ on the use of the latter). There is also a literal for `NSNumber` objects, your code:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:41]
```

can simply be replaced by `@41`.

Using the above literals will make your code shorter and easier to read.

Now your statement:

```
card.face = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", faces[i % 13]];
```

suggests a misunderstanding of how references and immutable objects work. An `NSString` object is *immutable*, once created its value will never change. The method `stringWithFormat:` constructs an `NSString` according to its format and arguments, which in this case is a single string, so you are just copying the string equivalent to:

```
card.face = [faces[i % 13] copy];
```

However a copy of an immutable object is just the original object. You know `faces` contains only immutable strings as you create it using string literals, so the above is equivalent to:

```
card.face = faces[i % 13];
```

**Important:** You can use a mutable, `NSMutableString`, reference as an `NSString` one by sub-classing, so the last step here dropping the `copy` is **only valid** if you know the reference is to an `NSString` object and not to an `NSMutableString` one.

Having used direct indexing on `faces` and `suits` you switch to long form:

```
card.prime = [[primes objectAtIndex:(i % 13)] intValue];
```

and in a few other places. All of them can be replaced by `[...]`, e.g.:

```
card.prime = [[primes[i % 13] intValue];
```

While you uses of division (`i / 13`) and remainder (`i % 13`) are all correct you might want to consider using two nested loops to avoid them, e.g. something like:

```
for(int suitRank = 0; suitRank < 4; suitRank++)
{  for(int cardRank = 0; cardRank < 13; cardRank++)
   {  // now use suitRank for i / 13 and cardRank for i % 13
```

The above is all just tidying up to make your code shorter, more readable, and less error prone. Now a more serious issue:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)createDeck:(id)sender {
   [sender removeAllObjects];
```

**Never** do this! While `id` has it uses it reduces the compilers ability to check your code is correct and can result in your code going wrong when it is run for simple errors the compiler would have caught. Here `sender` is clearly meant to be a reference to a mutable array, declare it as such:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)createDeck:(NSMutableArray *)sender
{
   [sender removeAllObjects];
```

Later (after applying the above use of literals) you have:

```
NSMutableArray *fiveCardHand = @[ cards[[pointerArray[0] intValue]],
                                  ...
                                ].mutableCopy;
//Check for hand rank.

fiveCardHand = [self organizeCardsRankOrder:fiveCardHand];
```

Here you:

1. create a mutable array
2. assign a reference to it to `fiveCardHand`
3. overwrite the reference in `fiveCardHand` with the result of `organizeCardsRankOrder:`

So here you *appear not* to have mutated the array referenced by `fiveCardHand` but instead changed the variable to reference a *different* array. You don't need to use mutable arrays to do that, you are mutating the variable holding the reference not the referenced array. Now "appear" was used here as you have not supplied the code of `organizeCardsRankOrder:`, maybe that method does mutate the array passed to it, if that is the case it does not need to also return it and there is no need for the assignment to the variable. So look at your code carefully here and decide whether you are mutating arrays or just variables and change it accordingly.

Finally you do not provide any declarations in the question for `_deck` and `_hand`. By naming convention you might be directly accessing the backing variable of a property (doing this is often best avoided), or accessing an instance variable, both of some unspecified class. Therefore we cannot provide any real help with these, just check that if they are connected to an instance that you are using the *same* instance everywhere you expect to - a common early error is to set an instance variable in one instance, try to read it from another instance, and then wonder why the value is different...

HTH, happy debugging!

Comment: thank you for your very in-depth response. I appreciate it. Unfortunately this is not homework, it's just something I wanted to attempt. I haven't programmed in a year or two properly so just trying to get back into it. I also didn't school in any sort of programming I taught myself PHP back in about 2007 then moved into Objective-C. Hence my patterns are generally from memory rather than by logic. However, thanks for your response and although it doesn't necessarily answer the intended question I will accept it as there isn't apparently an answer to be derived from this.